# CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

How to create CustomPage in Inno Setup with Edit Boxes for Serial Number?
E.g. 6x5chars or 7x5chars?

Script should check if all boxes are filled before Next button become available.

It would be also good if there could be Copy/Paste function implemented that would allow to fill up all Edit Boxes if the clipboard content matches the serial number pattern.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is one approach that uses the custom page where the separate edit boxes are created. You only need to specify the value for the `SC_EDITCOUNT` constant where the number of edit boxes is defined and the `SC_CHARCOUNT` what is the number of characters that can be entered into these edit boxes. If you are in the first edit box you may paste the whole serial number if it's in the format by the pattern delimited by the `-` char (the `TryPasteSerialNumber` function here). To get the serial number from the edit boxes it's enough to call `GetSerialNumber` where you can specify also a delimiter for the output format (if needed).

```pascal
[Setup]
AppName=Serial number project
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Serial number project

[code]
function SetFocus(hWnd: HWND): HWND;
  external 'SetFocus@user32.dll stdcall';
function OpenClipboard(hWndNewOwner: HWND): BOOL;
  external 'OpenClipboard@user32.dll stdcall';
function GetClipboardData(uFormat: UINT): THandle;
  external 'GetClipboardData@user32.dll stdcall';
function CloseClipboard: BOOL;
  external 'CloseClipboard@user32.dll stdcall';
function GlobalLock(hMem: THandle): PAnsiChar;
  external 'GlobalLock@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function GlobalUnlock(hMem: THandle): BOOL;
  external 'GlobalUnlock@kernel32.dll stdcall';

var
  SerialPage: TWizardPage;
  SerialEdits: array of TEdit;

const
  CF_TEXT = 1;
  VK_BACK = 8;
  SC_EDITCOUNT = 6;
  SC_CHARCOUNT = 5;
  SC_DELIMITER = '-';

function IsValidInput: Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(SerialEdits) - 1 do
    if Length(SerialEdits[I].Text) < SC_CHARCOUNT then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Break;
    end;
end;

function GetClipboardText: string;
var
  Data: THandle;
begin
  Result := '';
  if OpenClipboard(0) then
  try
    Data := GetClipboardData(CF_TEXT);
    if Data <> 0 then
      Result := String(GlobalLock(Data));
  finally
    if Data <> 0 then
      GlobalUnlock(Data);
    CloseClipboard;
  end;
end;

function GetSerialNumber(ADelimiter: Char): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(SerialEdits) - 1 do
    Result := Result + SerialEdits[I].Text + ADelimiter;
  Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
end;

function TrySetSerialNumber(const ASerialNumber: string; ADelimiter: Char): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  J: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  if Length(ASerialNumber) = ((SC_EDITCOUNT * SC_CHARCOUNT) + (SC_EDITCOUNT - 1)) then
  begin
    for I := 1 to SC_EDITCOUNT - 1 do
      if ASerialNumber[(I * SC_CHARCOUNT) + I] <> ADelimiter then
        Exit;

    for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(SerialEdits) - 1 do
    begin
      J := (I * SC_CHARCOUNT) + I + 1;
      SerialEdits[I].Text := Copy(ASerialNumber, J, SC_CHARCOUNT);
    end;

    Result := True;
  end;
end;

function TryPasteSerialNumber: Boolean;
begin
  Result := TrySetSerialNumber(GetClipboardText, SC_DELIMITER);
end;

procedure OnSerialEditChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := IsValidInput;
end;

procedure OnSerialEditKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var
  Edit: TEdit;
  EditIndex: Integer;
begin
  Edit := TEdit(Sender);
  EditIndex := Edit.TabOrder - SerialEdits[0].TabOrder;
  if (EditIndex = 0) and (Key = Ord('V')) and (Shift = [ssCtrl]) then
  begin
    if TryPasteSerialNumber then
      Key := 0;
  end
  else
  if (Key >= 32) and (Key <= 255) then
  begin
    if Length(Edit.Text) = SC_CHARCOUNT - 1 then
    begin
      if EditIndex < GetArrayLength(SerialEdits) - 1 then
        SetFocus(SerialEdits[EditIndex + 1].Handle)
      else
        SetFocus(WizardForm.NextButton.Handle);
    end;
  end
  else
  if Key = VK_BACK then
    if (EditIndex > 0) and (Edit.Text = '') and (Edit.SelStart = 0) then
      SetFocus(SerialEdits[EditIndex - 1].Handle);
end;

procedure CreateSerialNumberPage;
var
  I: Integer;
  Edit: TEdit;
  DescLabel: TLabel;
  EditWidth: Integer;
begin
  SerialPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Serial number validation',
    'Enter the valid serial number');

  DescLabel := TLabel.Create(SerialPage);
  DescLabel.Top := 16;
  DescLabel.Left := 0;
  DescLabel.Parent := SerialPage.Surface;
  DescLabel.Caption := 'Enter valid serial number and continue the installation...';
  DescLabel.Font.Style := [fsBold];

  SetArrayLength(SerialEdits, SC_EDITCOUNT);
  EditWidth := (SerialPage.SurfaceWidth - ((SC_EDITCOUNT - 1) * 8)) div SC_EDITCOUNT;

  for I := 0 to SC_EDITCOUNT - 1 do
  begin
    Edit := TEdit.Create(SerialPage);
    Edit.Top := 40;
    Edit.Left := I * (EditWidth + 8);
    Edit.Width := EditWidth;
    Edit.CharCase := ecUpperCase;
    Edit.MaxLength := SC_CHARCOUNT;
    Edit.Parent := SerialPage.Surface;
    Edit.OnChange := @OnSerialEditChange;
    Edit.OnKeyDown := @OnSerialEditKeyDown;
    SerialEdits[I] := Edit;
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = SerialPage.ID then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := IsValidInput;  
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CreateSerialNumberPage;
end;
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can make Inno prompt the user for a serial key by adding an [`CheckSerial()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#CheckSerial) event function.

If you want more control over the page, you can use one of the stock pages ([`CreateInput...Page`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptpages)) or a custom page in the setup wizard using [`CreateCustomPage()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_createcustompage.htm) and adding controls as you require.

See the [codedlg.iss](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Examples/CodeDlg.iss) example included with Inno setup.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to add a Serial key box, beneath the Name and Organisation text fields, is to add something like the following to your iss file.

```
[Code]

  function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
  begin
  // serial format is XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
  Serial := Trim(Serial);
  if Length(Serial) = 19 then
    result := true;
 end;
```

This can be usefully combined with

```
[Setup]
DefaultUserInfoSerial={param:Serial}
```

which will fill in the serial if previously entered for the install.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246105/how-can-i-set-the-serial-for-this-serial-form-inno-setup