# Verifying serial number against multiple values in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, verification, serial-number

So I'm trying to create an installer with a serial number verification in Inno Setup using this: 
[CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385319/custompage-for-serial-number-in-inno-setup)
^For the serial number page

[How can i set the serial for this serial form (Inno Setup)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246105/how-can-i-set-the-serial-for-this-serial-form-inno-setup#comment14806875_11262646)
^For the checking of the serial entered. Both are made by TLama!

So I'm trying to make the code use multiple serial numbers, I tried doing this (using the code from the second link):

```pascal
CanContinue := GetSerialNumber('-') = '62FFU-GA4N8-T8N6W-WLQJW-N6WLQ-AJKD6';
CanContinue := GetSerialNumber('-') = 'TEST1-RANDO-MFAKE-THING-YBLAB-BLA55';
```

but when doing that, only the second one will work.

I don't really understand the Inno Setup code all that much, but can anyone explain how to make this work please? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It didn't work as expected because you were overwriting the `CanContinue` value by the second line of code which led to work only for the second serial number.

You should store the returned value of the `GetSerialNumber` function to some local variable to avoid multiple function calls and use the `or` operator in the statement. Something like this (I've also removed the extra `CanContinue` variable, which was not much useful here):

```pascal
procedure OnSerialEditChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  S: string;
begin
  { store the returned value to the local variable to avoid multliple calls }
  S := GetSerialNumber('-');
  { enable the NextButton only when the serial number matches either first }
  { OR the second serial number string }
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled :=
    (S = '62FFU-GA4N8-T8N6W-WLQJW-N6WLQ-AJKD6') or
    (S = 'TEST1-RANDO-MFAKE-THING-YBLAB-BLA55');
end;
```