# Validating the serial number INNO setup?

Tags: inno-setup

Im using inno setup for creating a custom page and validating serial number l, now my doubt is that can i run a webservice when the user enters the serial number and clicks next button so that i can validate the serial number entered by the user on server side

How can i call a webservice when the user clicks the next button, is it possible to call webervice from the custom page of innosetup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to utilize WinHTTP in the `[Code]` section,

http://turngeek.blogspot.hk/2012/04/making-web-request-within-inno-setup.html

Comment: thnks a lot for it, was trying for this since 2 days......trying it out, but in the code in the article the where did the user call the webservice as there is no asmx in the code.....?

Comment: okkkk,i got it...WinHttpReq.Open('GET', MYURL, false);...MYURL is the parameter where i need to pass my webservice url..

Comment: `.Open` is the function you set the properties (URL, verb) for the request, `.Send` in fact sends out the request message. When you read `.Status` and `.ResponseText` you already get the response message and everything you need. It is better to have a REST web service, as in URL you can pass the serial number.

Comment: being new to inno setup and deployment, one final query is...i need to vaidate the license key serial number entered by the user, if the user enters the correct serial key then he should be able to proceed further with the installation.......is this possible with inno setup?

Comment: That's already discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385319/custompage-for-serial-number-in-inno-setup