# TLama's CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

TLama's code for creating a Serial Number page shown here [CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385319/custompage-for-serial-number-in-inno-setup)

currently detects for CTRL+V for pasting in a serial number; how can it be changed to also detect for SHIFT+INS?

Comment: Define one new constant `VK_INSERT = 45` and the condition in `OnSerialEditKeyDown` event method starting with `if (EditIndex = 0) and ... then` extend to `if (EditIndex = 0) and (((Key = Ord('V')) and (Shift = [ssCtrl])) or ((Key = VK_INSERT) and (Shift = [ssShift]))) then`.