# Pre-fill previously entered values in TLama's CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm using this awesome TLama's solution for Custom SerialNumber Page [CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385319/custompage-for-serial-number-in-inno-setup)

How can I pre-fill those values from previous installation?

I know about [GetPreviousData](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getpreviousdata.htm)/[SetPreviousData](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_setpreviousdata.htm) functions in Inno Setup, but don't know how to implement it here.

Any advice?

Comment: You may add a simillar function to `TryPasteSerialNumber` which will try read the serial from Registry or File. But first you have to write the Serial to registry or to file. Instead of `S := GetClipboardText` you should get the value from chosen place.

Comment: I've added the serial number setter function to the original post, so now you have `GetSerialNumber` function for `SetPreviousData` and `TrySetSerialNumber` function for `GetPreviousData`.

Comment: @TLama, I see you have changed the original post, but I'm still lost. Maybe a small code snippet will help me. Can you write an example please?