# Inno Setup: how to paste serial number by right-click mouse and paste

Tags: inno-setup

According this question [CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385319/custompage-for-serial-number-in-inno-setup), I already realized the serial number pasting by "Ctr+C" and "Ctr+V". Now I need to paste the serial number by right-click the mouse and paste.

Can I add a wndproc in the edit so that I can catch the WM_PASTE message?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from previous answer like this:

```
procedure OnSerialEditChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  Edit: TEdit;
  EditIndex: Integer;

begin
  Edit := TEdit(Sender);
  EditIndex := Edit.TabOrder - SerialEdits[0].TabOrder;

  if ((EditIndex = 0) and (IsValidInput = False)) then
  begin
    TryPasteSerialNumber;
  end;

  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := IsValidInput;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't solve my problem yet, I need to paste the serial number when I right-click the edit and click the "paste" option on the popup menu.