# Secure the installation of a software by prompting for a serial number

Tags: inno-setup, serial-number

I am working on a project (Java project) and using Inno Setup 5 to create an installer. How can I secure the use of the install.exe and ask a serial number during the installation?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is "key"? A password? Or a serial number? Or what?

Comment: I want a way to secure the software : offline with use of a serial. I don't know the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Inno Setup has a built-in functionality prompting for a serial number on the optional "User Information" page and verifying the entered number.

- set the [`UserInfoPage` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_userinfopage) to `yes`;
- implement the [`CheckSerial` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CheckSerial) to make the Inno Setup prompt the user for the serial number and to verify it;
- use the [`{userinfoserial}` constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=userinfoserial) in the [`[Registry]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection) to save the entered and verified number to registry.

```pascal
[Setup]
UserInfoPage=yes

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\My Company"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SerialNumber"; \
    ValueData: "{userinfoserial}"

[Code]

function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Serial = '123');
end;
```

[image]

---

For a more advanced implementation, see [CustomPage for Serial Number in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10385319/850848).

Comment: Nice. Thanks. It's a first step. Then I need to avoid the copy/paste with a regedit key ?

Comment: If I secure the installer, it's a good thing. But someone could copy the folder and use my soft without any problem. I think I need to lock the software if a regedit key was not created during with the installer.

Comment: So you want to store the serial number to registry? And make your application check the registry to be able to start? Or what?

Comment: Something like that, I guess.

Comment: I updated my last response to add some tips. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I works. I recommand to add in the InnoSetup script :

> Flags: uninsdeletekey

When the program is uninstalled, delete the entire key.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\MySoft"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "AppInfo";  ValueData: "value" ; Flags: uninsdeletekey
```

I used this [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0630.html) to recover the key in my soft.

```
value = WinRegistry.readString (
                WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,                             
               "SOFTWARE\\MySoft",          
               "AppInfo");
```

Comment: Do not use answer to comment on another answer. Use comments.

Comment: And if you have another question, [ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). And why would you need to avoid copy/paste anyway?

Comment: Or the `uninsdeletekeyifempty` and `uninsdeletevalue`.